# DCE/RPC - узнать переменные окружения или расположения системных папок

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, rpc

Можно ли с помощью [`DCE/RPC`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCE/RPC) узнать нужные переменные окружения или пути к 
системных папкам, таким  как `c:program file` или `home user directory`?

Среди этого многообразия технических [документов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj712081.aspx), может есть что-то?

Comment: А зачем вам RPC/DCE, когда все это достается через 1-2 API-функции?

Comment: С удаленного компьютера же надо узнать ...